# How do I move a local master and branch in progress to another laptop?

Tags: git

I'm a git newbie moving over from a project that used svn. My new dev team has a remote master I've cloned my local master from. I have the local master and a branch with development in progress but incomplete. My company sent me a newer laptop (I work remotely through a VPN) and I want to move my local repo to the new laptop without losing the work in progress in my branch. I don't want to involve the remote repository. All of the team members are relatively new to git so have no answer for me. What is the best way to do this?

Note: Windows 10 & Azure DevOps

Comment: A 1:1 direct copy of the whole directory should be sufficient. The only thing you would lose is any global git configuration (such as user name and email). Also: pushing an incomplete development branch back to a central repository is almost always a perfectly acceptable thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

This question is tagged `git` but appears to about `svn`. In either case, a full copy of the directories concerned to the new laptop should be sufficient. If you're using git over ssh, then ensure appropriate ssh credentials are copied too.

Comment: I WAS using svn (and a dozen others over the years). This project uses git and it is not exactly transparent. Everybody has a different answer to any question. With git pull (fetch & merge) should you use the merge strategy or the --rebase strategy for example? Everybody has his own opinions on which to use when. There's still a lot to learn - like about making sure ssh creds are copied.  Thanks guys.